# Represent field in DB by variable

Tags: vb.net

I have a project which is linked with a MDB file. I need to filter records of a table based on a condition, and both "field name" and the value or conditions should be passed to a Sub via variables. The select statement doesn't work. Did I miss something?

```
Dim Result() As DataRow
Dim strField As String = "asset_code"
Dim dblValue As Double = 3
Dim tblName as Datatable = AssetsDataSet.Assets
Result = tblName.Select(" '" & strField & "' = '" & dblValue& "' ")
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to loose the single quotes around the field name and as the data because it looks like it is numeric:

Result = tblName.Select(strField & " = " & cstr(dblValue) )

With string data you need to use a function:
Result = tblName.Select("textfield = " & cSQL(StringData) )

Function cSQL(psTextData As String) As String

```
' Replace any single quotes to be 2 single quotes
Return "'" + Replace(psTextData, "'", "''") + "'"
```

End Function

Comment: As  SLaks suggested you need to check any data put in a query. For example if the data came from a web page it could contain things that could corrupt your database.

Comment: If your field is a string you also need to make sure that it is surrounded by single quotes and single quotes within the string should be doubled.